# How to correctly solve functional equation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I want to solve the below functional equation:

Let $f : (0, ∞) \rightarrow R$ be a differentiable function satisfying the equation $$f(xy) = e ^ {xy - x - y}  (e ^ y  f(x) + e ^ x  f(y))$$ for all $x, y > 0$ and $f' (1) = e$.

I wrote the following code :

```
Clear[f, x, y]

eqn = f[x*y] == Exp[xy - x - y] * (Exp[y] * f[x] + Exp[x] * f[y]);

sol = RSolve[{eqn, f'[1] == Exp}, f[x], x];

fSol[x_] = f[x] /. sol[[1]];

fSol[x]
```

What is wrong with this code as it is not solving this equation and throwing error?

Comment: Lots of syntactic errors here, the most obvious being xy instead of x y.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: And should `f'[1] == Exp` be `f'[1] == Exp[1]` ?

Comment: @SavageTomato The equation is equivalent to   $e^{-x y} f(x y)=e^{-x} f(x)+e^{-y} f(y)$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equation is equivalent to   $e^{-x y} f(x y)=e^{-x} f(x)+e^{-y} f(y)$

```
eq = Exp[-x y] f[x y] == Exp[-x] f[x] + Exp[-y] f[y]
```

Possible "fixedpoints" are

```
Reduce[x y == x && x y == y, {x, y} ] 
(* (y == 0 && x == 0) || (y == 1 && x == 1) *)
```

**case  (x == 0 && y == 0)**

```
eq /. {x -> 0, y -> 0} (* => f[1]\[Equal]0 *)
sol0 = Solve[eq /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}, f[0]][[1]] (*f[0]==2 f[0]*) 
ode = D[eq, x] /. {y -> 0 } /. sol0 // Simplify(*E^-x (f[x] - Derivative[1][f][x]) == 0*)
sol = DSolve[{ode, f[0] == 0 }, f, x][[1]]
(*{f -> Function[{x}, 0]}*)
```

-> only trivial solution

**case  (x == 1 && y == 1)**  `see @ubpdqn's interesting answer`

```
eq /. {x -> 1, y -> 1} (* => f[1]\[Equal]0 *)
sol1 = Solve[eq /. {x -> 1, y -> 1}, f[1]][[1]] (*f[1]==0*)
ode = D[eq, x] /. {x -> 1 } /. sol1 // Simplify (*E y f[y] + E^y Derivative[1][f][1] == E y Derivative[1][f][y]*)
sol = DSolve[{ode, f[1] == 0 }, f, y][[1]](*{f -> Function[{y}, E^(-1 + y) Log[y] Derivative[1][f][1]]}*)
```

-> solution `{f -> Function[{y}, E^(-1 + y) Log[y] Derivative[1][f][1]]}`  (for arbitrary `f'[1]`)!

```
Show[{Plot[Evaluate@Table[f[x] /. sol, {f'[1], Subdivide[0, 2 E,10]}], {x, 0,2}], Plot[ f[x] /. sol /. f'[1] -> E, {x, 0, 2},PlotStyle-> Black]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Neat. As you express products to sums was a big clue logarithms involved. +1 :)

Comment: I think dg1 is not defined. Apologies if I have missed it.

Comment: @ubpdqn Thanks for the hint , `dgl`should be `ode`: Corrected!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a neater approach than my original answer:

Exploiting the observation of Ulrich Neumann:
$e^{−x y}f(xy)=e^{−x}f(x)+e^{−y}f(y)$

Define $h(x)= e^{-x}f(x)$, then this means
$h(xy)=h(x)+h(y)$.
Further $x=y=1 \implies h(1)=0$ and further $f'(1)=e \implies h'(1)=1\because h'(1)= -e^{-1} f(1)+ e^{-1}f'(1)$

So,

```
lhs = D[h[x y], x];
rhs = D[h[x] + h[y], x];
l = lhs /. x -> 1;
r = rhs //. {x -> 1, h'[1] -> 1}
hf = h /. DSolve[{l == r, h[1] == 0}, h, y][[1]];
Solve[hf[x] == Exp[-x] f, f]
```

yields: {{f -> E^x Log[x]}}

**Original Answer**

`RSolve` will not be helpful.

```
 expr = Exp[x y - x - y]*(Exp[y]*f[x] + Exp[x]*f[y]);
```

Note

```
Solve[f[1] == expr /. {x -> 1, y -> 1}, f[1]]
```

yields `f[1]->0` hence we know $f(1)=0,f'(1)=e$.

Now consider, $\frac{\partial f(x y)}{\partial x}=y f'( x y)$, evaluated at $x=1$:

```
 Simplify[D[expr, x] /. x -> 1] /. {f[1] -> 0, f'[1] -> E}
```

This yields: $y f(y)+e^y$, so $y f'(y)= y f(y)+e^y, y(1)=0$.

Solving this differential equation:

```
func = f /. DSolve[{y f'[y] == y f[y] + Exp[y], f[1] == 0}, f, y][[1]]
```

The solution is: $f(x)=e^x \log(x)$

Confirming:

```
func[x y]
Expand[expr /. f[a_] :> func[a]]
```

yields:

$e^{x y} \log(x y)$

$e^{x y} \log(x) + e^{x y} \log(y)$

These can be seen to be equivalent, which mean lhs and rhs of initial posing of problem are equal as desired.
I leave to OP or others to use Mathematica to establish equality.

Further, `D[func[x], x] /. x -> 1` yields $e$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @SavageTomato welcome to Mathematica Stackexchange. Others may have nicer approaches: more integrated, better simplifications. Thanks for accept at present. Good luck.

Comment: @ubpdqn Nice solution, which might be more direct. Knowing `f[1]==0` we get `eq = f[x y] == E^(-x - y + x y) (E^y f[x] + E^x f[y]);ode = D[eq, x] /. {x -> 1 } /. sol1 // Simplify;DSolve[{dgl, f[1] == 0 }, f, y]  (*{f -> Function[{y}, E^(-1 + y) Log[y] Derivative[1][f][1]]}*)`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann very nice. Feel free to post. As I have been accused before of using MMA/WL as typewriter, welcome other answers. It was clear by inspection x=y=1 -> f(1)=2f(1)…so I went on merry adventure

Comment: @ubpdqn Have a nice trip! Another possibility `x->0,y->0 -> f[0]==0` only gives trivial solution `f[x]==0` ...

Comment: @SavageTomato my approach is incorrect but lick. I encourage you to accept Ulrich Neumann answer. I have voted for his.